# What does this line "/dev/sda5: clean, 956436/30277632 files, 37421846/121093120 blocs" mean while booting?

Tags: boot, 16.04, filesystem

After I upgraded my Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04, I am getting a weird line on my screen each time I power on my laptop:

[image: mystery line]

```
/dev/sda5: clean, 956436/30277632 files, 37421826/123093120 blocks
```

What does this line mean?

I worry about the meaning of the numbers, because the first number says that some files were cleaned, and the second one says that some files were blocks...

Nothing special or complicated, just for general understanding.

Comment: ahh dont worry its probably like a disk checkup , everyone have it

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's a harmless message, rather a good news for you!!

While booting, by default, the root filesystem (filesystem containing mount point `/`), is gone through a filesystem check using `fsck`, this is the result of that check. If there were any error the filesystem would be mounted read only, rather than read-write.

Although this an assumption from my side, to be precise this is the `fsck` output for the filesystem created on partition `/dev/sda5`, as you can do `fsck` on any disk backed filesystem but by default `fsck` is not done on  filesystems other than the one having the root directory as mount point.

About the blocks, the filesystem divides the while partition into blocks, blocks are the minimal operational unit (so also the storage unit) to a filesystem. While writing, filesystem writes in full blocks i.e. if a file's actual size is 200 Bytes, it will take a block size space in the filesystem, hence on the underlying disk. For `ext4`, the block size is 4 KB.

In the message:

```
956436/30277632 files, 37421826/123093120 blocks
```

`956436` is the number of inodes used from a total of `30277632`(fixed at the time of filesystem creation), same goes for the blocks usage numbers.

Here "clean" after the partition means the partition is allright, there is no issue with it.

Comment: Rephrase: I'm pretty sure the numbers are the used and total amount of files (inodes), and the used and total amount of blocks in the filesystem. (That is, not a progress indicator.)

Comment: @ilkkachu I stand corrected, i have rechecked and you are correct. I thought it was an ongoing snapshot. edited..

Comment: `clean` means that the partition is marked as okay, and the actual test is skipped.

Comment: `clean` means the partition was unmounted cleanly and so no check is needed (as opposed to the journal-replay message you'd see after a power failure or other unclean shutdown).

Comment: `vivek@vivek:~$ df -Th
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs   32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     6.3G   18M  6.3G   1% /run
/dev/sda5      ext4      430G  408G     0 100% /
tmpfs          tmpfs      32G   76M   32G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs      32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda3      vfat       96M   29M   68M  30% /boot/efi
tmpfs          tmpfs     6.3G   84K  6.3G   1% /run/user/1000
` How to clear sda5 , as it is somehow taking up all the space