# “dev/sda1: clean, …” This message appears after I reboot the pc

Tags: command-line, 16.04, nvidia

After rebooting my Ubuntu, I get this message:

```
/dev/sda4: clean, 693755/24805376 files, 11233563/99206912 blocks
```

I reached Command Line by pressing Ctrl + Alt + F2 or F3, I tried:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt-get update
```

then, I tried to check if it purged:

```
dpkg -l | grep nvidia
```

nothing printed. Also I tried:

```
sudo systemctl start lightdm.service
```

and nothing happened :(!

I rebooted the pc again and same message comes to me.

Comment: If the system boots/loads up in a few seconds after that message, everything is good.  If system is not booting, please edit your question with problem.  On a working system we like that message, means file system is good.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does this line "/dev/sda5: clean, 956436/30277632 files, 37421846/121093120 blocs" mean while booting?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/809900/what-does-this-line-dev-sda5-clean-956436-30277632-files-37421846-121093120)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reinstalled nvidia driver and the pc works with me, solution:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-(version suitable for you) nvidia-settings
```

Comment: -1 That message has nothing to do with graphics drivers

Comment: @Parto, you are mistaken, this is a solution which indeed helped me very much, after many unsuccessful attempts with other solutions.